# Routing after lazy loading is loading wrong component in Angular6

Tags: angular, angular6

I had implemented lazy loading on already developed application but after implementing, it is loading Any other component other than Home page and this is happening with the Home page only. My root level routing is like this:

```
{path: '', redirectTo: 'home', pathMatch: 'full'},
  { path: '', loadChildren: './views/home/home.module#HomeModule'},
  { path: 'resetpass', loadChildren: './views/resetpass/resetpass.module#ResetpassModule'},
  { path: 'forgotpass', loadChildren: './views/forgotpass/forgot.module#ForgotpassModule'},
  { path: 'signup', loadChildren: './views/signup/signup.module#SignupModule'},
  { path: 'login', loadChildren: './views/login/login.module#LoginModule' },
  { path: 'otp',  loadChildren: './views/otp/otp.module#OtpModule'},
    { path: 'school', loadChildren: './views/school/school-home/school-home.module#SchoolhomeModule'},    
    { path: 'school/addstudents', loadChildren: './views/school/add-students/add-students.module#AddstudentsModule'},
    { path: 'school/managestudents', loadChildren: './views/school/manage-students/manage-students.module#ManagestudentsModule'},
    { path: 'school/ViewLogsDetails', loadChildren: './views/school/View-Log-Details/logdetails.module#LogdetailsModule'}, 
    { path: 'school/accountinfo', loadChildren: './views/school/accountinfo/accountinfo.module#AccountinfoModule'},
    { path: 'school/subscribe', loadChildren: './views/school/cals-subscribe/cal-subscribe.module#CalsubscribeModule'},
    { path: 'school/addstaff', loadChildren: './views/school/add-staff/add-staff.module#AddstaffModule'},
    { path: 'school/trans-track/:id', loadChildren: './views/school/trans-track/trans-track.module#TranstrackModule'},
    { path: '**', loadChildren: './views/home/home.module#HomeModule' }
```

On the home page, this loads AddstudentsComponent, even it should work just after login, here is the routing module for AddStudent:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { AddStudentsComponent } from './add-students.component';

const routes: Routes = [
    { path: '', component: AddStudentsComponent}
];

@NgModule({
    exports: [RouterModule],
    imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)]
})
export class AddstudentsRoutingModule { }
```

As soon as I change path from '' to something like 'school/addstudent', it start loading AddStaff component.

Entire application was working fine until I put Module in each component level. Don't know how to copeup.

Comment: there is no route for ``home``

Comment: I had mentioned few of Lazy Loading module in root level modules, this is why application was inconsistent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have included Lazy Loading Module in app.module.ts like this:

```
import { AddstaffModule } from './views/school/add-staff/add-staff.module';
```

But I have not done the same with other component level modules. So the application was behaving incosistantly.

What I did now is to remove Component Level Modules from app.module.ts, like this line was removed:

```
import { AddstaffModule } from './views/school/add-staff/add-staff.module';
```

And, it becam consistent.

Comment: You might have imported the module in your the `imports` array of your `@NgModule` object. the import you are mentioning has nothing to do with the inconsistency. When you import the module in another module, it is not lazy-loaded anymore.

Comment: FWIW I had the same problem - I had 4 lazy loaded modules, wanted to use a component from one in another one and just exported the component, then imported that module.  I am a bad person.  Don't be like me.